# Cannot assign "13": "Registerleson.leson" must be a "Classes" instance

Tags: django

I want to do a group registration, everyone who registered in the old leson will be registered in the new leson

Error:

```
Cannot assign "13": "Registerleson.leson" must be a "Classes" instance.
```

views.py:

```
def AddListGroup(request):
    oldleson = request.POST['termold']
    newleson = int(request.POST['termnew'])
    book = request.POST['book']
    price = request.POST['price']
    discount = request.POST['discount']
    darsad = request.POST['darsad']
    leson = Registerleson.objects.filter(leson=oldleson)

    if leson:
        for item in leson:
            register = Registerleson(
                student=item.student,
                leson=newleson,   
                book=book, 
                member_add=request.user.id,
                discount=discount,
                darsad=darsad,
                price=price,
            )
            register.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'ثبت نام گروهی با موفقیت انجام شد')
            return redirect('groupRegistration')
    else:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, 'هیچ زبان آموزی در کلاس مبدا ثبت نام نکرده است')
        return redirect('groupRegistration')
```

groupRegistration.html:

```
 <select class="form-control" name="termold">
      {% for item in kelasha %}
           {% if item.term.termjari != 1 %}
                <option value="{{ item.id }}">{{ item.sath.name }}</option>
           {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
 </select>

 <select class="form-control" name="termnew">
      {% for item in kelasha %}
           {% if item.term.termjari == 1 %}
                <option value="{{ item.id }}">{{ item.sath.name }}</option>
           {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      </select>
      <label style="margin-top: 20px">کتاب : </label>
      <select class="form-control" name="book">
           {% for item in books %}
                <option value="{{ item.id }}"> {{ item.name }}</option>
           {% endfor %}
      </select>

      <label style="margin-top: 20px">قیمت : </label>
      <input class="form-control" type="number" name="price" value="0">

      <label style="margin-top: 20px">تخفیف : </label>
      <input class="form-control" type="number" name="discount" value="0">

                    <label style="margin-top: 20px">تخفیف درصدی : </label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="darsad" value="0">


 <button class="btn btn-success" style="margin: 10px;border-radius: 10px;"> ثبت نام</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error mentioned, the variable `newleson` must be a Class. It's hard to guess without having the model what it could be. But I expect it should also be a `Registerleson` model object.

But you pass in an integer value `13`. If `newleson` is a `Registerleson` then you should pass in that specific object:

```
newleson_obj = Registerleson.objects.get(leson=newleson)
```

and later pass that leson in to the new object:

```
register = Registerleson(
    student=item.student,
    leson=newleson_obj,
    ...
```